# to make the for loop efficient and use of lists and dictionary in it

Tags: python

Can please suggest a way to make this following looping efficient?
the program mainly populates the 4 time frames from a main list 'val_rt_xxx' 
Each time frame is populated according the frame time variables 'fr_1,..fr_4'

```
# minimum time of the list of times - 'time_rt_min'
mn_time_rt = min(time_rt_min)

# The four time frames as dictionaries
frame_t = {}
frame_t['1'] = {}
frame_t['2'] = {}
frame_t['3'] = {}
frame_t['4'] = {}

# Creating empty lists in each frame dictionary
for fr in frame_t.keys():
    frame_t[fr]['rt_long'] = []
    frame_t[fr]['rt_lat'] = []
    frame_t[fr]['rt_data'] = []
    frame_t[fr]['rt_time'] = []

# There is the frame defined with respect to the mn_time_roti the minimum time 
fr_1 = mn_time_rt
fr_2 = mn_time_rt + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 15)
fr_3 = mn_time_rt + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 30)
fr_4 = mn_time_rt + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 45)

# populating the lists in dictionaries with appropriate values 
# from the main list 'var_rt_xxx' according to the time frames
for i in range(len(val_rt_time)):
     if val_rt_time[i] <= fr_1 :

          frame_t['1']['rt_long'].append(val_rt_long[i])
          frame_t['1']['rt_lat'].append(val_rt_lat[i])
          frame_t['1']['rt_data'].append(val_rt_data[i])
          frame_t['1']['rt_time'].append(val_rt_time[i])

     elif (val_rt_time[i] > fr_1 and val_rt_time[i] <= fr_2) :

          frame_t['2']['rt_long'].append(val_rt_long[i])
          frame_t['2']['rt_lat'].append(val_rt_lat[i])
          frame_t['2']['rt_data'].append(val_rt_data[i])
          frame_t['2']['rt_time'].append(val_rt_time[i])

     elif val_rt_time[i] > fr_2 and val_rt_time[i] <= fr_3:

          frame_t['3']['rt_long'].append(val_rt_long[i])
          frame_t['3']['rt_lat'].append(val_rt_lat[i])
          frame_t['3']['rt_data'].append(val_rt_data[i])
          frame_t['3']['rt_time'].append(val_rt_time[i])

     elif val_rt_time[i] > fr_3 and val_rt_time[i] <= fr_4:

          frame_t['4']['rt_long'].append(val_rt_long[i])
          frame_t['4']['rt_lat'].append(val_rt_lat[i])
          frame_t['4']['rt_data'].append(val_rt_data[i])
          frame_t['4']['rt_time'].append(val_rt_time[i])
```

Comment: Your loop is already O(N), you cannot really improve on that other than use more idiomatic Python. That'll improve readability, execution  speed will go up a little but not much.

Comment: I can't see anything but minor optimizations you could do. It might help a little to store all four variables in a list of tuples instead of four seperate lists (or maybe just loop through the four lists `zip`ed. If speed is a big concern and you are dealing with significant amounts of data, it may be best to use a language other than python (or at least something like psycho). Also do you mean to be comparing `val_rt_time` inside that loop? I may be mistaken but it looks to me like it should be `val_rt_time[i]`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you all for the reply.... @KSab - Yes it should be val_rt_time[i], I edited the post , dint reflect sooner, and I thought of zip , but it was of same complexity level , dint reduce the number of lines